# How do I add 'javascript' url scheme in HTML purifier module in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-modules, htmlpurifier

How can I can add the "javascript:xyz" url format for the URI.AllowedSchemes in HTML purifier module in drupal ?

I suppose this is the file I should modify [URI.AllowedSchemes](http://www.boonex.com/trac/dolphin/browser/trunk/plugins/htmlpurifier/standalone/HTMLPurifier/ConfigSchema/schema/URI.AllowedSchemes.txt?rev=14042) or is there any other config change I need to make. This is for the site moderator to publish bookmarklets and will not be exposed to outside world.

Comment: If you're going to allow arbitrary javascript, is it worth running htmlpurifier at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-uri-filter.html